# Axios request from express app missing arguments

Tags: node.js, express, http-post, axios

Im trying to make a POST request to a FacePlusPlus API.
At the moment I'm just running app.js with node, but I keep getting an error .

My axios request inside express app:

```
axios({
  method: "post",
  url: "https://api-us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/face/analyze",
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
  },
  data: {
    'api_key': '<My api key goes here>',
    'api_secret': '<My api secret goes here>',
    'image_url': 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/220453/pexels-photo-220453.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb'
  }
})
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

The Response error:

```
{ Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (/Users/Matt/webdev/test/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/Users/Matt/webdev/test/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:18:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/Users/Matt/webdev/test/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:192:11)
    at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1047:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:102:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)
  config:
   { adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
     transformRequest: { '0': [Function: transformRequest] },
     transformResponse: { '0': [Function: transformResponse] },
     timeout: 0,
     xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
     xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
     maxContentLength: -1,
     validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
     headers:
      { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'User-Agent': 'axios/0.17.1',
        'Content-Length': 212 },
     method: 'post',
     url: 'https://api-us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/face/analyze',
     data: '{"api_key":"*** i removed this for question ***","api_secret":"*** i removed this for question ***","image_url":"https://images.pexels.com/photos/220453/pexels-photo-220453.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"}' }

 ...
 ...


  data: { error_message: 'MISSING_ARGUMENTS: api_key' } } }
```

The data is obviously getting, sent, but why does it say missing argument?

Answer (score 0):

Try console logging the api-key through the response and see what you get, since it is telling you it is a missing argument. Your data is a string and not an object should it be like that, just out of curiosity?

Comment: The API server wasnt even able to read the request body because it turns out the api didnt accept application/json. Worked A-Ok when I sent form data in a query string. Thanks for your help though!